# How to communicate simultaneously in both ways on socket.io node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to send some data to a node.js server when some event triggers. In parallel, the server is supposed to send some data every 1 second to the client. I am using socket.io for this. Here is my code:
Server side:

```
app= require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

// request handler function, will send client file which include sliders and graph    
function handler (req, res) {    
var reqObj = urr.parse(req.url, true);
var reqPath = reqObj.pathname;
if ('/' == reqPath ) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function(err, data) {
if (err) {         
res.writeHead(500);
return     
res.end('Errorloadingclient.html');    }
res.end(data);
});    }    };

var slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4 ;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

// receive changed value of slider send by client
socket.on('ValSlider1', function(data){
slider1 = data ;
console.log("Slider 1 Value: " + data);    });
// same for three more sliders    });
// send received values back to client after every 1 second interval

setInterval(function () {
var data = slider1 + "-" + slider2 + "-" + slider3 + "-"    + slider4; 
socket.emit('packet', data);
},1000);    });    
app.maxConnections = 1;
```

Client side:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://smoothiecharts.org/smoothie.js"></script>

// slider 
<p id="ValSlider1"> Curr Val </p>
<input class = "mySlider1" type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="0"     min="0"     max="100" />
```

// similar for three more sliders
    Packet

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

// send changed value to server
$(".mySlider1").change(function() {
var sVal = $(this).val();
socket.emit('ValSlider1', sVal);
});
```

// similar for three more sliders

```
socket.on('packet', function (data) {
var valFromServer = data.split('-');
document.getElementById("ValSlider1").innerHTML =   valFromServer[0];
});

</script>
```

Now, I get data on the server side only when I use 'socket.emit()' twice in the client, where the server sends data at 1 second intervals.

Comment: Try shrinking your repro case until it is minimal.

Comment: I recommend using [`express.io`](https://github.com/techpines/express.io) instead of express/socket.io separately. It solves a lot of pitfalls and has great routing and session sharing support.

Comment: Please reduce the code amount to make this more understandable. Also some indentions within the code would be helpfull when trying to read the code.

Comment: Basically what i wanted to do is client.on(send data to server);

Comment: Basically what i wanted to do is, on client side: event.on(send data to server); on server side: client.on(receive data); and setInterval(send some data to client every 1 sec.). I tried above code. Client sends first two-three values, server also receive that, but then server not receive anything and only sends previous values

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall Since am doing node.js and javasript first time any working example of express.io will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i manage to do it in this way,
On server side

```
app= require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000),
io = require('socket.io').listen(3001);
publisher = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

On client side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
var socket2 = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

client will send data to server on 'socket', in response server will also send some data on same port. simultaneously, server will publish data on 3001 port at every 1 second interval which is received in client on ".on('data')" event of server1.